# Should works of Swami Vivekananda and other non-Vedic scholars be banned from this site?

Tags: discussion

Swami Vivekananda, and all neo-Vedantin acharyas, interpret Hindu scriptures to fit their own personal whims, reject important scriptures like the Dharma Shastras and Brahma Sutras, and routinely insult great, ancient Rishis like Vedavyasa, as well as some recognized Hindu scriptures, such as the Puranas.

For example, Vivekananda said:

> In the Gita the way is laid open to all men and women, to all caste
>   and colour, but Vyasa tries to put meanings upon the Vedas *to cheat
>   the poor Shudras.*

Here he is accusing Vedavyasa, a man of high importance in Hinduism, and an *Avesha Avatar of Vishnu*, of "cheating poor Shudras."

Who is this Vivekananda man? He was no Vedic scholar, he had no real Acharya, he never even did Vedadhyayanam, he was not even a Rishi. His works should not be accepted as authoritative on this site.

As per Manusmriti:

> Those Brāhmaṇas, by whom the Veda, along with its supplements, has
>   been learnt in the right manner, and who are guided directly by the
>   revealed texts,—shall be regarded as ‘cultured.’—(109)
>
> That which even a single Brāhmaṇa learned in the Veda decides to be
>   the law, shall be understood to be the highest law,—and not what is
>   asserted by ten thousand ignoramuses.—(113)

Vivekananda neither knew the Vedas (never did Vedadhyayanam), nor learned any of the Vedangas, and he wasn't a Brahmana.

Based on those Manusmriti verses above, it appears that Vivekananda is not an authority on Hinduism, and since this site is about Hinduism, it follows that the works of Vivekananda and other non-Vedic scholars, such as Western Indologists should not be allowed on this site, except as a *Purva Pakshin* view.

Answer (score 9):

We should allow views of all sects, be it Advaita, Visitadvaita, Dvaita, Shaiva, Vaishnava. Shakteya. Some sects or philosophies even criticize other sects as non-vedic but doesn't mean we shouldn't allow them. These criticisms and refutations are part and parcel of Sanatana Dharma from time immemorial. Different followers subscribe to different views.

> Who is this Vivekananda man? He was no Vedic scholar, he had no real
>   Acharya, he never even did Vedadhyayanam, he was not even a Rishi. His
>   works should not be accepted as authoritative on this site.

These are definitely not views of all Hindus on Vivekananda. Definitely he also has critics. Not just his views, even philosophies of AdiShankara, Ramanuja and other Acharyas are criticized. Many schools say other philosophies, except their own philosophy, are not in consistent with Vedas. If we have to disallow  such sects considering criticisms, then we should disallow all philosophies or sects of Hinduism.

We even allow words of Scholars who are against *Apaurusheyatva* of Vedas. If you don't agree with any answer, downvote it and move on.